# Does eloquent pivot tables work for multi-word table names?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two multi-word models, let's call them `FunkyModel` and `AnotherModel`.

Will creating a pivot table named `another_model_funky_model` work?

The docs and examples I've come across all use single word model names like this: model A - `User`, model B - `Address`, and pivot table will then be `address_user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it would work, you can also name it whatever you want, you just need to declare the table name in the relation (same goes for the foreign keys)

```
class FunkyModel
{

public function anotherModels()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(AnotherModel::class, 'pivot_table_name', 'funky_model_id', 'another_model_id');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you dive into the source code of the `BelongsToMany` relation function, you'll find that if you haven't provided a `$table`, the code will execute the function `joiningTable`. This uses the current model and the passed related class, snake cases the names and then puts them in alphabetical order of each other.

Simply said, no matter if you have a single word or a couple, the result will always be the 2 classes snaked, in alphabetical order. Note that the alphabetical order is applied by the default [php sort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).

Examples:

- Department + Occupation > `department_occupation`
- AwesomeModel + LessInterestingModel > `awesome_model_less_interesting_model`
- Role + UserPermission > `role_user_permission`

You can even try and see what the auto-generated name is by simply calling the following:

```php
(new Model)->joiningTable(OtherModel::class, (new OtherModel));
```

Comment: I love it, thank you for the shortcode for pivot table name resolution. never took the time to look it up.